# PostgreSQL pg_constraint's confupdtype / confdeltype columns using undocumented letter (space). What does it mean?

Tags: postgresql, pg-catalog

The doc at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html says:

> Foreign key update action code: **a** = no action, **r** = restrict, **c** = cascade, **n** = set null, **d** = set default

And does not mention a *space* at all. But it actually uses a space (ascii code 32) a lot:

```
ddevienne=> select '"'||confdeltype||'"', count(*) from pg_constraint group by confdeltype;
 ?column? | count
----------+-------
 "a"      |   242
 "c"      |   941
 " "      |  2210
 "n"      |   201
(4 rows)
Time: 3.968 ms
```

So what does that *space* mean? And why is it not documented?
I'm using PostgreSQL v12, but the doc is the same for v12 and v14 in that regard.

**Update (given the accepted answer):**
Looking at Foreign Key constraints only (`contype = 'f'`) does get rid of the *spaces* indeed.

```
ddevienne=> select '"'||confdeltype||'"', count(*) from pg_constraint where contype = 'f' group by confdeltype;
 ?column? | count
----------+-------
 "a"      |   242
 "c"      |   941
 "n"      |   201
(3 rows)
Time: 4.124 ms
ddevienne=> select '"'||confupdtype||'"', count(*) from pg_constraint where contype = 'f' group by confupdtype;
 ?column? | count
----------+-------
 "a"      |  1381
 "c"      |     2
 "n"      |     1
(3 rows)
Time: 3.361 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confdeltype` is `NOT NULL`, so it is set to a blank for constraints other than foreign key constraints.